# AngularJs nexted view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Hi I am going to start a project.
In tablet page contains list of items on left side and item detail on right side as shown in below image.[image]

In mobile It shows list of items on one page and detail of activity on another page, like below images.[image]

[image]

I have used AngularJs to  implemented this application like this(pseudo code)

### Index.html

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <boby>
     <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### List.html

```
<ul><li ng-repeat='item in items' >{{item.title}}</li></ul>

<div id="middleContent" ui-view style="padding-left: 320px;"></div>
```

---

### detail.html

```
<div>Acitivity detail <div>
```

### config.js

```
app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('List', {
            url: '/List',
            templateUrl: 'Partial/List.html',
            controller: 'ListController'
        })
        $stateProvider.state('Detail', {
            url: '/Detail/:id',
            templateUrl: 'Partial/Detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailController'
        })

        $stateProvider.state('TabletList', {
            url: '/TabletList',
            data: { 'parent': 'tablet' },
            templateUrl: 'Partial/List.html',
            controller: 'ListController'
        })


        $stateProvider.state('TabletList.Detail', {
            url: '/Detail/:id',
            templateUrl: 'Partial/Detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailController',
        })

    })
```

---

### In Controller.js

```
app.controller('ListController',function(){

if($(window).width() > mobileView )( $state.go('TabletList.Detail'))

})
```

---

In List.html I have use next view

```
<div id="middleContent" ui-view style="padding-left: 317px;"></div>
```

It get loaded in case of tablet . otherwise it is useless there.

Is there some simple way to handle this scenario. please help

with regards

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: have you thought of using a mobile first framework such as Twitter Bootstrap or Skeleton (getskeleton). Skeleton is simple and lets you style it, bootstrap has a tone of css stuff

Comment: I have handle mobile and tablet view in complex way (i.e. define nested view in list.html , and define complex routing state ). Is there some other way to handle this scenario